# Django / Apache / Ubuntu Static files not being served

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, django-staticfiles

Everything was working fine until I moved from my local PC to a web server (AWS Ubuntu). I am using Apache with WSGI adapter.

`DEBUG = FALSE` so this is a live production environment.

I followed all the guides I could and have been at this for several days and still can't figure out why none of my images or styles are displaying.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how static files work and there may be a simple reason why this isn't working but I can't figure it out.  I have followed so many guides and am at a loss.

Yes I have run `collectstatic`, but all this seems to do is throw all my static files into the static folder.  Not sure what the purpose of this is and I am having trouble understanding it on the django website.

You can view my site here:  http://13.56.18.7/

The site loads without styles, If you check Chrome Dev tools, it shows none of my files being found:

[image]

Build:

[image]

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app_main.views import (home_page, services_page, history_page, offers_page, contact_page)
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('services/', services_page),
    url(r'^services/', services_page, name='services_page'),
    url(r'^history/', history_page, name='history_page'),
    url(r'^offers/', offers_page, name='offers_page'),
    url(r'^contact/', contact_page, name='contact_page'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

apache2.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/build/DoneRitePlumbing
WSGIProcessGroup www-data
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing/wsgi.py

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /build/DoneRitePlumbing/media/
Alias /static/ /build/DoneRitePlumbing/static/


<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the head of my base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

Home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block contentHome %}

<style>
  .parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("{% static 'images/FrontMain-2.png' %}");
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}


      {% block contentContact %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block contentServices %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block contentHome %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block contentOffers %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block contentHistory %}
      {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your website and the error in the console, I think, changing

```
STATIC_URL="/static/"
```

to

```
STATIC_URL="http://13.56.18.7/static/"
```

in settings.py in your production should solve your problem.
The `{% static 'css/styles.css' %}` you are using in the template should set `href` to `/static/css/styles.css` but instead it's setting it to `/build/DoneRitePlumbing/static/css/styles.css`. I cannot tell why this is happening from the provided information. Can you update the question with a complete template which is being loaded on the homepage?

Comment: You are a legend!  That worked.  But I am still running into one more issue.  My homepage is still not loading some images/styles.  The rest of the page looks fine except for 2 images + the top portion is not styled.

I updated the question with my home.html and  base.html, if you can help me out with this, I will mark yours as the answer.

Thank you so much for you assistance.

Comment: getting chrome dev tools says "http://13.56.18.7/static/images/FrontMain-2.png" is still not found (404)